# Parsec returns [Char] instead of Text

Tags: haskell, type-inference, parsec

I am trying to create a parser for a custom file format. In the format I am working with, some fields have a closing tag like so:

```
<SOL>
<DATE>0517
<YEAR>86
</SOL>
```

I am trying to grab the value between the `</` and `>` and use it as part of the bigger parser.

I have come up with the code below. The trouble is, the parser returns `[Char]` instead of `Text`.  I can pack each `Char` by doing `fmap pack $ return r` to get a text value out, but I was hoping type inference would save me from having to do this.  Could someone give hints as to why I am getting back `[Char]` instead of `Text`, and how I can get back `Text` without having to manually pack the value?

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import           Data.Text
import           Text.Parsec
import           Text.Parsec.Text

-- |A closing tag is on its own line and is a "</" followed by some uppercase characters
-- followed by some '>'
closingTag = do
    _ <- char '\n'
    r <- between (string "</") (char '>') (many upper)
    return r
```

Answer (score 4):

`string` has the type

```
string :: Stream s m Char => String -> ParsecT s u m String
```

(See [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.5/docs/Text-Parsec-Char.html) for documentation)

So getting a `String` back is exactly what's supposed to happen.

Type inference doesn't change types, it only infers them. `String` is a concrete type, so there's no way to infer `Text` for it.

What you *could* do, if you need this in a couple of places, is to write a function

```
text :: Stream s m Char => String -> ParsecT s u m Text 
text = fmap pack . string
```

or even

```
string' :: (IsString a, Stream s m Char) => String -> ParsecT s u m a
string' = fmap fromString . string
```

Also, it doesn't matter in this example but you'd probably want to import `Text` qualified, names like `pack` are used in a number of different modules.

---

As  Ørjan Johansen correctly pointed out, `string` isn't actually the problem here, `many upper` is. The same principle applies though.

Comment: I think `many upper` is more relevant than `string` here, because `between` only returns the result of its third parser argument.

Comment: I see the type of `many upper` is `ParsecT s u m [Char]`

I was under the impression that `[Char]` values could be used as `Text` without having to manually pack them, if the OverloadedStrings extension was turned on?

Comment: OverloadedString is a syntactic extension, not a type-system extension.  In particular, it reads string literals (things in quotation marks) as being in the IsString class.

Comment: The OverloadedStrings extension doesn't help you here because it only affects string literals in the source code of your program, but not strings that have been created by your program at runtime.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Oh you're right. I somehow garbled the order of arguments for between here.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you get `[Char]` here is that `upper` parses a `Char` and `many` turns that into a `[Char]`. I would write my own combinator along the lines of:

```
manyPacked = fmap pack . many
```

You could probably use type-level programming with type classes etc. to automatically choose between `many` and `manyPack` depending on the expect return type, but I don't think that's worth it. (It would probably look a bit like Scala's CanBuiltFrom).